# Python3: No module named httpcore.backends

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting a weird import error:

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httpcore
>>> import httpcore.backends
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httpcore.backends'
```

As far as I can tell httpcore is installed correctly. It just seems to not be fully loading.

Any ideas?

I've tried upgrading pip. Uninstalling and re-installing httpcore.

Comment: What does `dir(httpcore)` report?

Comment: `httpcore.backends` doesn't exist but `httpcore._backends` does. the `_` in `_backends` implies that it is a private module though and should not be used in other code.

Answer (score 2):

Today in a 0.17.3 release ([changelog](https://github.com/encode/httpcore/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0173-5th-july-2023) - [#699](https://github.com/encode/httpcore/pull/699)) the backend implementations moved to [a private subpackage](https://github.com/encode/httpcore/tree/master/httpcore/_backends). Don't import that.

Import them from top-level `httpcore`, as [the documentation shows](https://www.encode.io/httpcore/network-backends/).